# Remove localhost dependency of docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am working on tensorflow serving docker image
I have a docker command to start object detection server that is as follows:

```
sudo docker run -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/home/ajinkyabobade93/keras-retinanet/retinanet_savedmodel,target=/models/retinanet/1 -e MODEL_NAME=retinanet -t tensorflow/serving &
```

My question is each time I run this docker I have to specify path `/home/ajinkyabobade93/keras-retinanet/retinanet_savedmodel` this path is from my personal computer. I want to put this folder inside docker image so that I do not have to specify path every time from my local host.

How do I run this docker container such that the source directory is located inside the docker image and not on my PC ?

Comment: Build a custom image and copy the files you want there.

Comment: @leopal how do I remove dependency of ```--mount type=bind``` ? what is --mount type for ?

Answer (score 0):

the mount bind is a technique to bind a volume to your container to save and write data in, there are 2 main techniques for this **mount bind** and **volumes**
https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

you can easily make a dockerfile to store your configuration to easy use it on any machine

Comment: does the above command mean copy from source and paste it in target "/models/retinanet/1" ? Also does target represent folder inside docker image ?

Comment: It 's not copying it's a link from the inside to the outside, in other word the folder /models/retinanet/1 inside the container we be linked and point to /home/ajinkyabobade93/keras-retinanet/retinanet_savedmodel outside the container, if you deleted something from outside it wont be available inside and vise versa